# Find DLL name by having name of the Namespace

Tags: c#

In the code there is a line like this:

```
Company.Security.Logs.LogEvent myLog = null;
```

Now in another project I want to do the same but I don't know which "reference" should I add to my project? So how do I know in which of the references in this project we have this Security class?

Comment: If you right click on "Company" and select "Go To Definition", it should tell you the name of the DLL at the top of the definition source.

Comment: By using the documentation?... you do have documentation right?

Comment: @Mansfield a namespace can span multiple assemblies.  They should see where `LogEvent` is defined instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the class name in Visual Studio and Go to Declaration. This will take you either to a DLL view or code view, either of which will tell you which assembly the class lives in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Visual Studio "Go to Definition" (or F12) when the caret is over the name of the type, in this case, `LogEvent`. it will take you to a condensed API source file in the text editor that will have the first lines looking something like:

```
#region Assembly System.Windows.Forms.dll, v4.0.0.0
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll
#endregion
```